# Onclick rotate icon 180 degrees using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am needed to select all three icons and be able to have them rotate 180 when a user clicks on them. With the current code written, it is only targeting the first arrow icon, allowing it to turn 180 and back. Yet when I click on the other two icons, they do not rotate/ AND the first icon rotates even though I didn't click on the first icon.

```js
const arrowFlip = () => {
  let div = document.getElementById("nav__links");
  let icon = document.getElementById("icon");
  let open = false;

  div.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (open) {
      icon.className = "menu-arrow-down";
    } else {
      icon.className = "menu-arrow-down open";
    }

    open = !open;
  });
};
arrowFlip();
```

```css
.menu-arrow-down {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 1s linear;
}

.menu-arrow-down.open {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav__links" class="nav__links">
  <div class="desktop__nav">
    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">Product</a>

      <img id="icon" class="menu-arrow menu-arrow-down" src="./images/icon-arrow-light.svg" alt="arrow" />
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Overview</li>
        <li>Pricing</li>
        <li>Marketplace</li>
        <li>Features</li>
        <li>Integrations</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">Company</a>
      <img id="icon" class="menu-arrow menu-arrow-down" src="./images/icon-arrow-light.svg" alt="arrow" />
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Team</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Careers</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">Connect</a>
      <img id="icon" class="menu-arrow menu-arrow-down" src="./images/icon-arrow-light.svg" alt="arrow" />
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Newsletter</li>
        <li>LinkedIn</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is why IDs are to be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs need to be unique.

Delegate the click - it is much simpler

```js
document.getElementById("nav__links").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains('menu-arrow-down')) { // make sure we only target elements with this class
    tgt.classList.toggle('open');
    // here you can test tgt.classList.contains('open') to see the state
  }
});
```

```css
.menu-arrow-down {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 1s linear;
}

.menu-arrow-down.open {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav__links" class="nav__links">
  <div class="desktop__nav">
    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">Product</a>

      <img class="menu-arrow menu-arrow-down" src="./images/icon-arrow-light.svg" alt="arrow" />
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Overview</li>
        <li>Pricing</li>
        <li>Marketplace</li>
        <li>Features</li>
        <li>Integrations</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">Company</a>
      <img class="menu-arrow menu-arrow-down" src="./images/icon-arrow-light.svg" alt="arrow" />
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Team</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Careers</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">Connect</a>
      <img class="menu-arrow menu-arrow-down" src="./images/icon-arrow-light.svg" alt="arrow" />
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Newsletter</li>
        <li>LinkedIn</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you mplungjan! Super clean, the best important part is that I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add event listeners to all arrows, that way you won't need an id:

```js
let allArrows = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-arrow");

allArrows.forEach(arrow => {
  arrow.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.className = this.className === "menu-arrow-down open" ? "menu-arrow-down" : "menu-arrow-down open";
  });
});
```

```css
.menu-arrow-down {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 1s linear;
}

.menu-arrow-down.open {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav__links" class="nav__links">
  <div class="desktop__nav">
    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">Product</a>

      <img id="icon" class="menu-arrow menu-arrow-down" src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" alt="arrow" />
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Overview</li>
        <li>Pricing</li>
        <li>Marketplace</li>
        <li>Features</li>
        <li>Integrations</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">Company</a>
      <img id="icon" class="menu-arrow menu-arrow-down" src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" alt="arrow" />
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Team</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Careers</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">Connect</a>
      <img id="icon" class="menu-arrow menu-arrow-down" src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" alt="arrow" />
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Newsletter</li>
        <li>LinkedIn</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </div>
```

Comment: I do not recommend this approach. It is inelegant and adds too many event handlers

Comment: I see. Will keep that in mind. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Thank you Prosy! Always helping out!!

Answer (score 1):

Like the others wrote: an id has to be unique. Furthermore you don't need it since you simply can use the target of the event and toggle its class `.open` if it has the class `menu-arrow`.

```js
document.getElementById("nav__links").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target.className.includes('menu-arrow')) {
    event.target.classList.toggle('open');
  }
});
```

```css
.menu-arrow-down {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 1s linear;
}

.menu-arrow-down.open {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav__links" class="nav__links">
  <div class="desktop__nav">
    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">Product</a>
      <img class="menu-arrow menu-arrow-down" src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x120" alt="arrow" />
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Overview</li>
        <li>Pricing</li>
        <li>Marketplace</li>
        <li>Features</li>
        <li>Integrations</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">Company</a>
      <img class="menu-arrow menu-arrow-down" src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x120" alt="arrow" />
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Team</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Careers</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">Connect</a>
      <img class="menu-arrow menu-arrow-down" src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x120" alt="arrow" />
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Newsletter</li>
        <li>LinkedIn</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is identical to mine posted well before yours, except yours lack any  test of the target

Comment: Oh, that's true. I didn't see that. But the test isn't necessary - so i don't want to delete the answer...

Comment: Your lack of test will trigger to code on anything in #nav__links.
If I add `.open { background-color:red }` then anything clicked in #nav__links will change background color.

Comment: Sorry to rain on your parade. That is a very poor test. It is true for `not-a-menu-arrow` or `menu-arrow-left`

Comment: Then it should be modified if there will if other classes with ```menu-arrow``` in it will be used...

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `id` attribute is unique and cannot be used with multiple elements. `getElementById` will return the first element with the `id` of `icon`, producing the result you are seeing. To fix, I suggest passing a parameter to your function, whether it's an `event` or simply a number. In this example, I'll use a number:

```js
let open = false;
const arrowFlip = (number) => {
  let icon = document.getElementsByClassName("icon")[number];
  if (open) {
    icon.className = "icon menu-arrow-down";
  } else {
    icon.className = "icon menu-arrow-down open";
  }
  open = !open;
};
```

```css
.menu-arrow-down {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 1s linear;
}

.menu-arrow-down.open {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav__links" class="nav__links">
  <div class="desktop__nav">
    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">Product</a>

      <img class="icon" onclick="arrowFlip(0)" class="menu-arrow menu-arrow-down" src="./images/icon-arrow-light.svg" alt="arrow" />
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Overview</li>
        <li>Pricing</li>
        <li>Marketplace</li>
        <li>Features</li>
        <li>Integrations</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">Company</a>
      <img class="icon" onclick="arrowFlip(1)"class="menu-arrow menu-arrow-down" src="./images/icon-arrow-light.svg" alt="arrow" />
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Team</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Careers</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">Connect</a>
      <img class="icon" onclick="arrowFlip(2)"class="menu-arrow menu-arrow-down" src="./images/icon-arrow-light.svg" alt="arrow" />
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Newsletter</li>
        <li>LinkedIn</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </div>
```

The `onclick()` on each image will trigger this function, sending a number parameter, allowing the correct arrow to be referenced. Then, when it flips, the code will know what image the user is referencing to.